# the chef execute resource, what does the "creates" parameter do?

Tags: chef-infra

In the chef **execute** resource, the  "**creates**"  property/parameter... what does that do exactly?  I'm sure it's straightforward, but can someone explain please?  Thank you.

https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html

creates
Ruby Type: String
Prevent a command from creating a file when that file already exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It tests for the file that is specified before running the execute. If the file already exists, it will not run that execute. If the file does not exist, it will run the execute.

Answer (score 4):

`creates "/foo"` is equivalent to `not_if { File.exist?("/foo") }`.